# Kubuntu 16.04 lts no wifi. Doesn't even show in menu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kubuntu

I just installed 16.04 from a live usb and poof, it acts like wifi doesn't exist. It only shows airplane mode, nothing else. I haven't tried plugging in the Ethernet yet, can't for a few, but I have my phones data and a usb cable.

I've tried a handful of fixes I've read about but haven't found the cure.

Everything from rfkill unblocking to installing the bcmwl-kernel-source driver, which won't even install.

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 02)
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4311 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [103c:1374] 
   Kernel driver in use: wl 
   Kernel modules: ssb, wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

You installed a wrong driver. Connect to the internet and run:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```